# How to specify address location in axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, apache-axis

I use to generate wsdl from java calss axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin. Below I cited a passage pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <className>Path_to_ws_class</className>
                <outputFileName>src/main/webapp/webservice.wsdl</outputFileName>
        <schemaTargetNamespace>http://test.test/xsd</schemaTargetNamespace>
                    <wsdlVersion>${project.version}</wsdlVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java2wsdl</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But it generates in the bottom of wsdl file:

```
<wsdl:port name="WebServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="axis2:WebServiceSoap11Binding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/MerchantWebService"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

I don't need following part, because my web service is not available by this link:

```
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/MerchantWebService"/>
```

Is it possible to specify location as parameter in plugin configuration?
locationUri doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
<locationUri>http://localhost:8080/AppRootContext/services/MerchantWebService</locationUri>
```

to your

```
<configuration>
```